# git woes - when do a pull, it says its going to delete everything

Tags: github

Have an existing repo in git-hub with the projects files.

On a new machine, got into the target directory, e.g. myproject, and do this:

$ git init

$ git remote add origin https://github.com/myco/myproj.git

$ git pull (this downloads lots of files)

$ ls (no files)

$ git branch --set-upstream master origin/master

$ ls (no files)

$ git status ( shows all the files are marked for deletion! )

I have used this recipe before, no idea why doing a checkout of a repo causes it to delete all the repos files.

If I try and do the git branch before the git pull, it gives an error.

I cant use git clone, as ultimately, I need to have the files checked out into an eisting directory which already will have some project donfig files (not in git).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is in fact the exact sequence of commands you followed, then here are some comments to help you understand where you are:

```
$ git init
```

Since it seems like you entered an empty directory (on a new machine, ...), this creates a new repository out of your current directory. This repository has no objects, no `master` branch yet, no commits, etc...

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/myco/myproj.git
```

This adds your origin repository and shouldn't be a problem.

```
$ git pull (this downloads lots of files)
```

This does two things - `git fetch` to collect all objects, branches, etc. that your `origin` repository currently has but your local repository doesn't (i.e. everything, since you're in a currently empty repository), followed by `git merge`. The `merge` phase should have failed here, with a message the the effect of "you didn't tell me what you want to merge, so I'm not going to do it".

```
$ ls (no files)
```

Right. You still haven't checked anything out, and since the `git merge` above failed, it never got to the point of updating your working directory.

```
$ git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

Now you are creating a `master` branch that has `origin/master` as its upstream, and as its starting point. However, this does not check out the branch, which leaves your working directory in the same state it was before, i.e. empty.

```
$ ls (no files)
```

You still have not checked anything out, so this is expected.

```
$ git status ( shows all the files are marked for deletion! )
```

`git` compares your empty working directory with what it thinks should be there, and determines that you must have removed everything.

What you really wanted to do there is this:

```
$ cd directory/where/you/want/your/repository
$ git clone https://github.com/myco/myproj.git
$ cd myproj
```

Then, copy your additional project config files into place.

If you really want to do it all the manual way, use `git fetch` instead of `git pull`, and after your `git branch ...` line, do a `git checkout master` (or do `git checkout -b master origin/master` in place of the `git branch ...` line, which implicitly does the branch setup before checking out the files).

Comment: Hi, very good analysis.  The recommended solution you give wont work in this case, as we cant have the files created in a sub dir, we need them in the current dir.  Will try the fectch - git checkout master you suggest, thanks!